# convert timestamp format to integer in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have timestamp value in the format "01-JAN-00 10.05.54.170489000 AM". When I tried to convert to integer using the format "yyyymmddhhmm24missff":

```
select to_number(to_char(date_column,'yyyymmddhhmm24missff') from table_name;
```

I am getting the value as 20000101100554170489.The last 3 digits are missing. I need exact value as 20000101100554170489000.

How can I keep those last three digits in my number?

Comment: Do you need to code this in Java?

Comment: Your query is missing a closing parenthesis and has an extra `mm` making it invalid. But with those corrected it seems to give the correct result. Which version of Oracle are you using, and on which platform?

Answer (score 1):

Your query (with minor correction) gets the result you wanted when I run it with a plain timestamp, supplied via a CTE:

```
set numwidth 23
alter session set nls_timestamp_format = 'DD-MON-RR HH:MI:SS.FF AM';

with table_name (date_column) as (
  select to_timestamp('01-JAN-00 10.05.54.170489000 AM', 'DD-MON-RR HH:MI:SS.FF AM')
  from dual
)
select date_column, to_number(to_char(date_column,'yyyymmddhh24missff')) as result
from table_name;

DATE_COLUMN                                      RESULT
------------------------------- -----------------------
01-JAN-00 10:05:54.170489000 AM 20000101100554170489000
```

The only way I can see to get the result you actually have is if your timestamp column is actually constrained to that precision; i.e. `date_column timestamp(6)`:

```
with table_name (date_column) as (
  select cast(to_timestamp('01-JAN-00 10.05.54.170489000 AM', 'DD-MON-RR HH:MI:SS.FF AM')
    as timestamp(6))
  from dual
)
select date_column, to_number(to_char(date_column,'yyyymmddhh24missff')) as result
from table_name;

DATE_COLUMN                                      RESULT
------------------------------- -----------------------
01-JAN-00 10:05:54.170489000 AM    20000101100554170489
```

It seems odd to want to show more precision than the value is actually allowed to have, but if you really want to always include those last three zeros then you can override the column precision by using `ff9`:

```
with table_name (date_column) as (
  select cast(to_timestamp('01-JAN-00 10.05.54.170489000 AM', 'DD-MON-RR HH:MI:SS.FF AM')
    as timestamp(6))
  from dual
)
select date_column, to_number(to_char(date_column,'yyyymmddhh24missff9')) as result
from table_name;

DATE_COLUMN                                      RESULT
------------------------------- -----------------------
01-JAN-00 10:05:54.170489000 AM 20000101100554170489000
```

---

A timestamp (or date) doesn't have an intrinsic format, you are just seeing it converted to a string by your client, probably based on your session NLS settings. I've run an `alter session` to match what you seem to be using. Notice that even when I constrained the data type to `timestamp(6)`, the client's default formatting using `ff` still showed nine digits of precision. Seeing all nine when you query the table doesn't mean the values can actually have that much precision, and the last three digits displayed will always be zeros in this case.